# Translating strings with variables using Google Translate

Tags: internationalization, translation, google-translate, translate

I was trying to find this information on Google (obviously) and could not find anything relevant. Let's say I have the following strings to translate:

> Beer in London

Which can also be

> Beer in Paris

Or

> Beef Wellington in London

Basically from a code perspective the string look something like:

```
%s in %s
```

Where the first variable is a "type of food" and the second is a "city"

Is there a way to leverage Google translate to translate there type of strings? I could not find any information on their API documentation nor any example online. We could think that one way to get this to work would be to provide context in the variables, such as:

```
{Beer|Beef Wellington|Cheese|Poutine} in {London|Paris|Sydney}
```

Is it possible to do this with Google Translate or any other API if Google doesn't support this?

Comment: I've never seen a machine translating something like this. That is a task for a professional translator.